# How to clone a GitHub repo without Git installed?

Tags: node.js, git, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a VSCode extension. The extension is supposed to clone a GitHub repo to the current workspace. I thought the npm package git-clone would do the job. But as far as I can see, it only works with Git installed. There are also other similar npm packages that require Git. The users of the extension do not need Git, so I don't want to use anything that requires Git to be installed. So how can I easily clone/copy a repo without using Git?

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
async function cloneIt(workspace: any) {
    const shell = require('shelljs');
    var clone = require('git-clone');

    try {
        if (typeof workspace !== 'undefined' && workspace) {
            var targetPath = workspace + "\\\\microbit-stub";
            shell.cd(workspace);
            shell.config.execPath = String(shell.which('node'));
            shell.pwd();
            await clone('https://github.com/makerbit/microbit-stub.git', targetPath)
            return Promise.resolve();
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Console.log:

```
ERR spawn git ENOENT: Error: spawn git ENOENT
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

- Windows 10
- Typescript 4.3.2

Comment: So you actually want a full git repository and not just the code of one branch, right? Because the later you can easily get via the "Download ZIP" button within the GitHub website.

Comment: Without a git client installed, a full git clone won't be much use - unless your plugin will also provide other commands in the repository, in which case maybe something based on [libgit2](https://libgit2.org/) is what you're looking for? Either way, this comes down to a recommendation question, which is off-topic as explained in the [help].

Comment: I have updated my question: I only need code from one branch. Sorry for not being 100% precise in my question.

Comment: @IMSoP, my extension will provide other commands as well. I'll check out libgit2. Thanks.